# How to get a vector of column names of one particular type only

Tags: r

I am looking for a clever way of getting a vector composed of only column names that are factors:

```
sample <-data.frame(cbind(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                          ticker=c("A","A","AA","AA","AAA","AAA"),  
                          value=c(33,23,454,532,3421,3421)))
sample$id <- as.numeric(sample$id)
```

In the above data frame, code shoule return both these column names but not id:

`"ticker" "value"`

Looking for a non-looping, base solution if possible. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Do not use `cbind` like that when making a data.frame. Because in your example, `id` will get converted to a character to get combined with `ticker` and then when turned into a data.frame, all three columns will be factors. Just do `sample<-data.frame(id= ..., ticker=..., value=...)`

Comment: just wondering if you are looking for sample[,2:3] if you are looking only for column names colnames(sample[,2:3])

Comment: Great point MrFlick - been converting them after binding - in retrospect that was a nuisance. That's way I love stackoverflow, you post a question and get much more than an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(You shouldn't give your objects the same name as base functions, in this case `sample`.)

```
names(sample)[sapply(sample, is.factor)]
```

Answer (score 1):

the ignored little `*pply` brother, `rapply`

```
sample <-data.frame(cbind(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                          ticker=c("A","A","AA","AA","AAA","AAA"),  
                          value=c(33,23,454,532,3421,3421)))
sample$id <- as.numeric(sample$id)

rapply(sample, class, classes = 'factor')
# ticker    value 
# "factor" "factor"
```